# ERROR : Why After "10" value in not incremented?

Tags: c#, vb.net

`TableName = CourseMaster`

`Column Name = CourseCode`

ever time it takes max value =9 .. !
and 9 + 1 = 10 .. (value incrmented by 1 )..!

why it is nt taking MAX value 10 ?? 
Anybody please help, tell me where i m wrong... ??

```
//  Finding Max Term CourseCode
string query1 = "SELECT MAX(CourseCode) FROM CourseMaster ";
SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);
comm1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

string s;
s = comm1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
label3.Text = s;
int i;
i = Convert.ToInt32(s) + 1;
s = i.ToString();
label7.Text = s; 

comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
comm1.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Question not clear! Are you incrementing or finding the MAX value?

Comment: What do you mean by "error"? Your question is hopelessly unclear at the moment. (Why are you executing it as a *non-query* at the end?)

Comment: What is the error? and the question needs to be a bit more clear

Comment: @Nadeem_MK : Both ,,  finding MAX value from CourseMaster and incrementing that value by 1 ...

Comment: Ok, I bet your code is varchar.. then @jyparask answer is correct.

Comment: yup CourseCode is VARCHAR :(

Comment: @JonSkeet : comm1.ExecuteNonQuery(); B'coz after incrementing ,, coursecode coursename Inserted in Database ....!

Comment: @Neelofar_Ahmed: But `comm1` is still just a `SELECT` statement... at least with the code you've provided. If there's more relevant code, you should have shown that.

Comment: @JonSkeet : hmmmm that was my fault ..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If CourseCode is of char/varchar or any other string like type then `9` is greater than `10`.

Maybe this would help:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,CourseCode)) FROM CourseMaster
```

Comment: +1 for psychic debugging :)

Comment: CourseCode (varchar) :/

Comment: @jyparask : its wrking :D

Thank you very much :)